# Is there such a thing as an "executable directory"?

Tags: linux, executable

In MacOS you can name a folder with the suffix `.app` and it will be launchable from the GUI as an application based on an internal folder structure convention.

Does such a thing exist in Linux?

Can I, for instance, mark a directory as an executable and when attempting to execute that directory (either from the CLI or from the GUI) Linux will look for a `./main` (or similar) internally to execute.

EDIT:

This is mostly just a curiosity but in terms of behavior, what I was hoping to know was if there was some way to mark the folder with some meta-data that told Linux to use it as a proxy for a binary held inside - something like:

```bash
mkdir hello-world.app

# Create executable inside folder
echo "#!/bin/bash" > hello-world.app/bin/main
echo "echo Hello World" >> hello-world.app/bin/main

# Add some kind of meta-data to tell Linux what to do when executing folder
echo "execute=bin/main" > hello-world.app/app_manifest

# Mark as executable
chmod +x ./hello-world.app

# Run folder
./hello-world.app

# "Hello World"
```

My thinking was, it would be a convenient low effort way to distribute applications along with their dependencies, documentation while also serving as a convenient destination for configuration.

I would imagine if a software requires a dynamic library that differs to the one installed on your system, you could just download the appropriate one and put it in `hello-world.app/lib` and the binaries would prefer the local library to the system one.

I know the convention for Linux is to use `/usr/local` or `/opt` for software/binaries and `/var` for configuration but that can be a bit hard to follow as not everyone follows the conventions. Software on different distributions implement things differently.

I know we have tried to solve this by containerizing applications with Docker, Flatpak, AppImage, etc and they are great - but I was hoping for something deadly simple.

Having folders `/apps` and `$HOME/apps` with applications that keep their config within their relative folders is kind of nice - at least on the surface.

Comment: What would it do though? I mean, what does "executing" a directory mean? What is the behavior you are expecting? All directories need to be executable for your user to be able to `cd` into them, so you need to give us a bit more detail to understand what you are expecting. Some default file name to be executed when you "execute" the dir?

Comment: Given that  directories are not able to detect when a extension/suffix is assigned I think you can create a file with the same name as the directory: `fuzz.app`. But you will have to create a new `mimetype` for your `.app` filetype. Then, you will have to assign a program (in this case may be a `shell script`)  for opening that type of files, so when you make *double-click* the shell script checks the filename and run the necessary commands (remember that the filename should be the directory name plus `.app`).

Comment: Btw, using mimetypes and assign a program to open the files seems to work only in a file manager. So if you want to execute the file with `.app` fextension rom a terminal (by using `./fuzz.app` ) you will have to use `binfmt_misc` kernel capability.

Comment: FWIW, you don't seem to be able to "execute" a directory on MacOS either.  When I try to execute /Applications/<appname>.app, I get: "zsh: Permission denied"  I would expect that it would follow the UNIX convention of using the execute bit to determine whether I'm able to change to that directory, and the ability to "run" a .app directory is strictly GUI magic.

Answer (score 6):

What you describe for MacOS is a GUI abstraction (finder, mostly); not an operating system function or actual property of the directory.

So, the same doesn't exist for any graphical file manager/shell for Linux I'm aware of. There's quite a few conventions that don't usually apply to applications on Linux that make would make that unfeasible.

Comment: The closest I know of is the auto-execute action when mounting a storage device such a USB thumb drive.  Still not a function of the OS, as you pointed out.